# php curl via proxy send which mac address

Tags: php, curl, proxy, mac-address

I doing curl connection via curl using free proxies. I wonder curl send my mac address or proxy ips mac adress.
How can I find mac address that I send via curl?

Comment: You could use a network protocol analyzer like wireshark to watch your traffic. Unfortunately, this question has nothing to do with programming, so I'll vote to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Yes that looks like its not about programing. but if I wrote curl codes it will be about programing? I have a curl funtion and its usually using by everyone. So no need to write.

Answer (score 1):

curl doesn't control what MAC address is used or have a way of doing this.  That's up to the OS/networking stack and whatever adapter was used to make the request.

You can easily spoof the MAC address in Linux and instruct curl to use the adapter with the spoofed address (using `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` or `--interface`).

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I request to a website. Can it see my mac adress? or other info about me expect my header or cookies?

Comment: The MAC address does not make it through to the web server, but it may possible through other means.  The MAC address is not part of TCP headers / Layer 3 so it is not directly accessible through socket functions.